# What is 'Active Reading' meant to imply in the edit reason field?

Tags: discussion, edits, edit-summary

I've noticed a few times the phrase 'Active Reading' in the edit summary, such as on this [revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/372116/4):

> Active reading [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OnePlus_5 http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance (the last section)].

Looking up the [term](https://help.open.ac.uk/active-reading#:%7E:text=Active%20reading%20simply%20means%20reading%20something%20with%20a%20determination%20to%20understand%20and%20evaluate%20it%20for%20its%20relevance%20to%20your%20needs):

> Active reading simply means reading something with a determination to understand and evaluate it for its relevance to your needs.

Doesn't really clear things up. Is the editor saying they have tried to actively understand/interpret my question so I should trust the edit is in earnest, or that it was difficult to understand and the edit was sorely needed?

I'm not sure what the relevance is or how I should take the summary differently than a summary without that phrase?

Comment: I have noticed this as well. I think that the editor is encouraging you or anyone else looking at the revisions to understand **why** they made the edit. In the case of the linked revision, they are linking to the Wikipedia page for the OnePlus phone to show how the brand should be formatted.

Comment: I think Peter Mortensen does that when he's adding links for context? Never seen anyone else use the term

Comment: Also note that, when you're a prolific editor, it is useful (even necessary) to have some standard, pre-made explanations to stick in the edit field.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've always understood this (based on e.g. [this interview](https://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/27/peter-mortensen-editor-in-chief/)) as Peter Mortensen's way of saying that he was reading the post while actively improving it with edits here and there. I don't think Peter has ever read a post outside of the edit box. Active reading is simply meant to convey that habit.

Comment: Active reading actually has a theory behind it. The idea is that not all sentences engage the reader equally and more engagement leads to better understanding of the material. Thus such rewrites should result in more engaging sentences/paragraphs.